# Can I pass a <script> into a meta refresh URL without php?

Tags: php

hoping someone can help me out.

I need to pass a token from the url into my page, more specifically a meta refresh url.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1] || ''
    );
}
</script>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://redirect.com/?subid=<script>document.write(getURLParameter('subid'))</script>">
```

As you can see in the content= section, I am trying to pass the token in my url into the subid= by using the following script:

```
<script>document.write(getURLParameter('subid'))</script>
```

But since it's insude the content=" " quotes, the script is not being recognized. I've also tried the following and it's not working either:

```
"+getURLParameter('subid')+"
```

I have gotten this to work using php, but this file will be hosted on a CDN, so I can run any php codes on there.

Does anyone have some suggestions on how this can be done?

My apologies if I haven't explained this correctly, but I'm not very well versed in this field as you can probably imagine.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot nest HTML tags, not even `<script>` tags, inside the attributes of other HTML tags.

What you can do, however, is to use Javascript to perform the redirect directly, e.g.

```
window.location = "http://example.com/?subid=" + getURLParameter("subid");
```